# What is the difference between "repeatable read" and "snapshot isolation"

Tags: sql, database, isolation-level

Repeatable read is defined as

> a higher isolation level, that in addition to the guarantees of the
>   read committed level, it also guarantees that any data read cannot
>   change, if the transaction reads the same data again, it will find the
>   previously read data in place, unchanged, and available to read.

Which seems very similar to snapshot isolation.

How is repeatable read different from the Snapshot isolation level?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Snapshot" guarantees that all queries within the transaction will see the data as it was at the start of the transaction.

"Repeatable read" guarantees only that if multiple queries within the transaction read the *same* rows, then they will see the same data each time. (So, different rows might get snapshotted at different times, depending on when the transaction first retrieves them. And if new rows are inserted, a later query might detect them.)

Comment: From https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/consistency-model/ I understand that repeatable read allows phantoms meaning that "if a transaction performs a query asking for rows matching a condition twice, the second execution might return more rows than the first. For example, something like select * from orders where value > 1000 might return orders (a, b, c) the first time and (a, b, c, d) the second time". Multiple tables appear not to be required.

Comment: @Javier: Thanks for your comment! I see how my parenthetical note could have been confusing. I've adjusted it now, and incorporated your example, which is very helpful. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Snapshot isolation is called "Repeatable Read" in PostgreSQL and in MySQL. It is called "serializable" in Oracle DB. IBM DB2 uses "repeatable read" to refer to serializability.

SQL standard doesn't have the concept of snapshot isolation that was defined years later, this is the reason for the naming confusion.

As a result, nobody really knows what repeatable read means. But, it's reasonable to assume that they are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say a transaction starts at time t1,

In Snapshot Isolation : when a transaction starts at time t1, it perceives a consistent snapshot of the entire database as it was precisely at t1. Thus, if a row is read at time t1, t1+d, or even later, the data fetched will always be consistent with the state of that row at t1.

But in case of Repeatable Read, things are a bit different, if the transaction starts at time t1 but doesn't immediately read a particular row. Now, if another transaction modifies that row and then our transaction reads it for the first time at t1+d, it will see the modified value. From that point on, any subsequent reads of that row (say at t1+d+e or later) during the transaction will show the same value as it was at t1+d.
It ensures that once a row is read, its value remains consistent throughout the transaction. But, it does not guarantee that the row's value is consistent with its state at the very beginning of the transaction (t1) unless it was read at t1.

Comment: im currently working on a little presentation about isolation levels. at least in mssql this statement about snapshot isolation is not correct.
snapshot isolation reads the data only when first accessed. i have a sql showcase here but its too many characters for a comment i think.